# Can I select a dynamically added p element with it's child button?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following dynamically added p element.  The enclosing div is in the DOM. I want to use the button to remove the p.

```
<div class="prime_ben">
<p class=”beneficiary”>
ADDED: John C Smith, Son <button class="remove_ben” type="button">REMOVE</button>
</p>
</div>
```

There are a lot of references (previous questions) here on how to use the .on method to add a click function to a dynamically added elements (like the button in my example).  But can’t figure out how to have the function act on the parent element.  I know I could add the click function to the p itself and just have clicking anywhere on the p remove it, but that isn’t what I want.  I just want the “REMOVE” text to be a click-to-remove button.
This code removes the button alone.

```
$('.prime_ben').on('click', 'button.remove_ben', function() {
    this.remove();
});
```

I’d like to use something like this:

```
$('.prime_ben').on('click', 'button.remove_ben', function() {
this.parent.remove();
});
```

I know it’s not working because the parent p is undefined (not in the DOM). Is there a way to select parent or sibling elements to the element selected with the .on method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were almost there. you have attached the delegated event correctly and parent element exists when you are performing remove button click:

```
$('.prime_ben').on('click', 'button.remove_ben', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: @user1028866: glad it helps :)